# ROS2 colcon build fails with ModuleNotFoundError for Python dependency in virtual environment

Tags: python, cmake, virtualenv, ros2, colcon

When trying to build my ROS2 project, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` when compiling one of the C modules, due to a missing dependency called `em`:

```
% colcon build --cmake-clean-cache
Starting >>> r1_messages
--- stderr: r1_messages                                                                     
CMake Error at /Users/mryall/src/mawson/ros2-iron-build/install/share/rosidl_adapter/cmake/rosidl_adapt_interfaces.cmake:57 (message):
  
  execute_process(/opt/homebrew/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3.12
  -m rosidl_adapter --package-name r1_messages --arguments-file
  /Users/mryall/src/mawson/r1-ros/build/r1_messages/rosidl_adapter__arguments__r1_messages.json
  --output-dir
  /Users/mryall/src/mawson/r1-ros/build/r1_messages/rosidl_adapter/r1_messages
  --output-file
  /Users/mryall/src/mawson/r1-ros/build/r1_messages/rosidl_adapter/r1_messages.idls)
  returned error code 1:

  Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
    File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
    File "/Users/mryall/src/mawson/ros2-iron-build/install/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rosidl_adapter/__main__.py", line 19, in <module>
      sys.exit(main())
               ^^^^^^
    File "/Users/mryall/src/mawson/ros2-iron-build/install/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rosidl_adapter/main.py", line 53, in main
      abs_idl_file = convert_to_idl(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/Users/mryall/src/mawson/ros2-iron-build/install/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rosidl_adapter/__init__.py", line 18, in convert_to_idl
      from rosidl_adapter.msg import convert_msg_to_idl
    File "/Users/mryall/src/mawson/ros2-iron-build/install/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rosidl_adapter/msg/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
      from rosidl_adapter.resource import expand_template
    File "/Users/mryall/src/mawson/ros2-iron-build/install/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rosidl_adapter/resource/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
      import em

  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'em'

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /Users/mryall/src/mawson/ros2-iron-build/install/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_generate_interfaces.cmake:132 (rosidl_adapt_interfaces)
  CMakeLists.txt:14 (rosidl_generate_interfaces)

---
Failed   <<< r1_messages [4.13s, exited with code 1]
```

My ROS2 installation was built with a Python virtual environment, which I have activated. But even though the virtual-env is activated and all the required libraries are installed with `pip`, the ROS modules built with CMake don't seem to be able to find it.

I tried to check that the `em` library was installed. Running `pip install empy` confirms that it is already installed:

```
% pip install empy
Requirement already satisfied: empy in /Users/mryall/src/mawson/ros2-iron/iron_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages (3.3.4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake modules in ROS2 do not automatically pick up the virtual environment used by the shell which calls `colcon`. (This is [apparently an intentional decision by the ROS2 maintainers](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/1094), who don't seem to understand the purpose or operation of virtual environments very well.)

You can fix this by asking `colcon` to pass the [`Python3_EXECUTABLE` parameter to CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython3.html#result-variables), using the `$VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable from your shell with the active virtualenv:

```bash
% colcon build --cmake-args -DPython3_EXECUTABLE="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python"
```

Fortunately, once the right binary is known, Python is smart enough to find the libraries which are installed in the virtualenv.

This enables C++/CMake modules in your ROS2 code to find all their Python dependencies.